# Where to fill out SQLite if user input isn't needed? (Beginner)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have done a lot of research about the SQLite database, and have already created a SQLite custom helper that extended SQLiteOpenHelper. However, I don't understand where to actually create the database and fill it out. I am trying to have the database be created immediately; I have all the information that needs to be inserted. In other words, no user input is required to fill it out.

Is the best practice to create an individual java class or activity that fills out the database, that can then be accessed by the activities?

Thanks - did a lot of research on creating the database and helper, just having trouble understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to have the database be created immediately; I have all the information that needs to be inserted.

Create the SQLite database on your development machine. Package it in `assets/` and [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to ship it with your app. Then, you can query from that data (e.g., to display it to the user).